# Using named groups in a DirectoryMatch directive

Tags: apache-2.2, regex, directory

I have the following directive in my httpd.conf:

```
<DirectoryMatch ^/path/(?P<SI>[^/]+)/logs/bibi>
    php_admin_value open_basedir /path/?P=<SI>/
</DirectoryMatch>
```

The pattern recognition for `(?P<SI>[^/]+)` works, but I don't find how to use it back with the instructions within the directive. The site http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html is very little helpful (syntax not working with my 2.2 apache) but at least they mention the possibility:

> Regular expressions containing named groups and backreferences are
>   added to the environment with the corresponding name in uppercase.
>   This allows elements of filename paths and URLs to be referenced from
>   within expressions and modules like mod_rewrite.

```
<DirectoryMatch ^/var/www/combined/(?<SITENAME>[^/]+)>
    require ldap-group cn=%{env:SITENAME},ou=combined,o=Example 
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Any idea? I want to use a named group into instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document to which you refer is for the current version of Apache. Within the `<DirectoryMatch>` documentation, there is clarification

> From 2.4.8 onwards, named groups and backreferences are captured and written to the environment with the corresponding name prefixed with "MATCH_" and in upper case...

As you're using a version of Apache earlier than 2.4.8 you won't have access to this facility.

Comment: you are right, I overlooked the version problem...

Comment: if you did have > apache 2.4.8, how would you do this...